# Writeline overwriting the last line

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to writeline into a text file this works accept it appears to overwrite the last line each time. I would like it to write to the next line instead of overwriting. Here is the code I'm using

```
 Dim FileNumber As Integer = FreeFile()
 FileOpen(FileNumber, "c:\Converted.txt", OpenMode.Output)
 PrintLine(FileNumber, convertedDir)
 FileClose(FileNumber)
```

Comment: Use OpenMode.Append to append instead of overwrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an old (VB6/VBA) code, better use the .NET `StreamWriter`:

```
Dim append As Boolean = True
Using writer As System.IO.StreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\Converted.txt", append)
    writer.WriteLine(convertedDir)
End Using
```

`append` indicates whether the given file should be appended. Nonetheless, as suggested by Boris B., you can set this variable always to `True` because `StreamWriter` is capable to deal with both situations (existing file or not) automatically.

In any case, I am including below the "theoretically right" way to deal with `StreamWriter` (by changing the `append property` depending upon the fact that the given file is present or not):

```
Dim append As Boolean = False
Dim fileName As String = "c:\Converted.txt"
If (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName)) Then
    append = True
End If
Using writer As System.IO.StreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName, append)
    writer.WriteLine(convertedDir) 'Writes to a new line
End Using
```

Comment: Thank you for the update. I have just tried that code. It is still overwriting the last line. The code before is copying folder directory's to a new location. I was hoping that it it would write the converted directorys as a new line so i would have a log of the folders created. at the moment it is just writing the very last folder to the converted.txt

Comment: @user2693561 This code writes to a new line every time. If the file c:\Converted.txt does not exist, it creates it and writes the first line. If this file already exists, you should set the append flag to true and will keep writing new lines. I will update my code right now to ensure that you are using it rightly.

Comment: @user2693561 please, test the new code I included and confirm that it writes every time to a new line.

Comment: There is no need for that `File.Exists` call and the `Dim append`, if you specify `New System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName, true)` the file will be appended if exists and created if it doesn't.

Comment: @BorisB. thanks for the comment, I will update my answer right away. To be honest, I usually rely on this approach (always true), although only under very specific conditions, because I wasn't 100% sure that the streamwriter performance on this front was perfect in any case.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick solution based on existing code change the line

```
FileOpen(FileNumber, "c:\Converted.txt", OpenMode.Output)
```

to

```
FileOpen(FileNumber, "c:\Converted.txt", OpenMode.Append)
```

However, you should really update your method of writing files, since FileOpen and similar are there just for compatibility with older VB & VBA programs (and programmers :). For a more modern solution check out varocarbas' answer.

Comment: Your answer is incomplete: you are assumming that the file is there without letting the OP know about this being a requisite. Also I don't think that you should support the reliance on old code.

Comment: @varocarbas: No I am not assuming anything. `FileOpen` with `OpenMode.Append` will create the file if it doesn't exist, the existence of the file is not important. As for reliance on old code, that is debatable to say the least. The OP has shown his existing code and asked what is wrong with it, I merely provided the answer on his own terms. If he had asked "How can I..." or "What is the best way..." then I'd probably go with `My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText`.

Comment: (I haven't ever used FileOpen with VB.NET, just assumed that it worked as proposed). You are right on this issue of replying what the OP is expecting (and that's why my +1), although I do think that when someone comes with a so old code, the best thing to do is telling him about newer, adaptable alternatives.

Comment: @varocarbas: I agree, that's what your answer is for :) Updated the answer.